# NamedDestinations shifted to page destination

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to merge PDF's, while transferring nameddestinations to new merged file, its shifted to page destination instead of named, please verify the code below.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To bookOrder.SelectNodes("//fileInfo/filename").Count - 1
        reader = New PdfReader(bookOrder.SelectNodes("//fileInfo/filename").Item(i).InnerText)
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations()
        n = reader.NumberOfPages
        tempBookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader)

        If i = 0 Then
            document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            pdfCpy = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(outputPdf, FileMode.Create))
            document.Open()
            SimpleBookmark.ShiftPageNumbers(tempBookmarks, page_offset, Nothing)
            page_offset += n
            If tempBookmarks IsNot Nothing Then
                bookmarks.AddRange(tempBookmarks)
            End If

            totalPages = n

        Else

            SimpleBookmark.ShiftPageNumbers(tempBookmarks, page_offset, Nothing)
            If tempBookmarks IsNot Nothing Then
                bookmarks.AddRange(tempBookmarks)
            End If

            page_offset += n
            totalPages += n
        End If

        For j As Integer = 1 To n
            page = pdfCpy.GetImportedPage(reader, j)
            pdfCpy.AddPage(page)
        Next

        pdfCpy.AddNamedDestinations(SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, False), page_offset - n)


        reader.Close()
    Next
```

Its working fine, but link destination changed from named to page... Please let me know where i need to correct to sort out this issue.

Comment: To rephrase your question: you instruct iText to consolidate named destinations using `ConsolidateNamedDestinations()` a function of which the documentation says: "Replaces all the local named links with the actual destinations." http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#consolidateNamedDestinations() Now you say that the named links are replaced with actual links. This isn't a bug report because the method works as expected. But what is the question?

Comment: Thanks Bruno, your comment enlighten me towards the answer, if I remove reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations(), it works great..

Comment: OK, I didn't understand the question, but since removing `ConsolidateNamedDestinations()` solves your problem, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instruct iText to consolidate named destinations using `ConsolidateNamedDestinations()`.
This function replaces all the local named links with the actual destinations.
If you remove this method from your code, named destinations will not be altered.

Comment: while using this `ConsolidateNamedDestinations` method, how about the fitting, for example named destination doesn't have fitting option, how its setting fit page... its default to fit page or we can set it as different..

Comment: Either I don't understand your question or you don't understand the concept of destinations. If the latter, please go to https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/ and download the first chapters of this book for free. Go to section 3.5.2.1 and read all about the way destinations are defined.